# display:fixed element inside the parent element using the contain property

Tags: css

I have HTML and CSS like this:

```
  <div class="container">
    <section>section</section>
    <footer>
      <span>footer</span>
      <button>top</button>
    </footer>
  </div>
```

```
section {
  height: 90vh;
  background: green;
  margin: 10px 0;
  color: white;
}

footer {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

footer button {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 100000;
}
```

The above rendering result is below

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXOU5.png)

Then, to improve rendering speed, I added containment to the container.

```
.container {
  contain: content;
}
```

Then, the behavior will be as if position: fixed is disabled.

[problem screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzsw1.png)

Is this a bug? Or is it a specification?
I looked at [MDN page about contain](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block), but I couldn't quite understand it.

Comment: It's a specification. It's part of why it improves performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
1) Declare <button> outside <footer> 
2) declare the same css but , remove right :0
   set position:sticky and left:100vw;
you will be good to go, if I assume as per your description .If not, kindly describe the output in more specific details
```

Modified Code :

```
    <div class="container">
        <section>section</section>
        <footer>
          <span>footer</span>
    
        </footer>
            <button>top</button>
      </div>
    section {
      height: 90vh;
      background: green;
      margin: 10px 0;
      color: white;
    }
    
    footer {
      height: 100px;
      background: blue;
      color: white;
    }
    
     button {
      background: red;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      position: sticky;
      bottom: 0;
      left : 100vw;
      z-index: 100000;
    }
```